# Recursive Self Join To Unpack Distribution Lists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of "Lists", this table contains 2 columns [ListName] and [MemberName], however the member name can either be the name of a person, or the name of another list (nested lists) - The data is coming from an external source.

```
CREATE TABLE Lists
(
ListName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
MemberName varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

There is nothing stopping an eventual "self-reference" on List Names

e.g.

```
List01 - Contains List02
List02 - Contains List03 and List04 
List03 - Contains List01
```

What I am looking for is

1) A way of determining if there are any nested self-references

2) If not then returning a single consolidated list containing all nested lists

e.g.

```
List01 - List02Member01
List01 - List01Member02
List01 - List01Member03
List01 - List02Member01
List01 - List02Member02
List01 - List03Member01
List01 - List04Member01
List02 - List02Member01
List02 - List02Member02
List02 - List03Member01
List02 - List04Member01
```

etc..

i.e. A fully expanded list for each list where the nesting has been unwound

I suspect that CTE will be involved in the answer somewhere, but currently I'm struggling to even see how to start this one.

Example Source Data - In the Lists table (Obfuscated)

```
ListName        MemberName
========        ==========
Domain\List01   Domain\Member01
Domain\List01   Domain\Member02
Domain\List01   Doman\Member03
Domain\List02   Domain\Member04
Domain\List02   Domain\Member02
Domain\List02   Domain\List03
Domain\List02   Domain\List04
Domain\List03   Domain\Member05
Domain\List03   Domain\Member06
Domain\List03   Domain\List05
Domain\List04   Domain\Member07
Domain\List04   Domain\Member08
Domain\List05   Domain\Member09
Domain\List05   Domain\List01
Domain\List01   Domain\List02
```

Comment: May I ask why the database was designed this way? I would think it would have been better to have a separate table which held the relationship between lists. Plus if there could be a "self-reference" wouldn't that cause an infinite loop??

Comment: You have to loop trough the list using `WHILE` or `CURSOR` and for each row create another WHILE loop to grab the referring list

Comment: @RyanWilson - The table design is based on data being exported by an external system, and at load time we don't know which "members" are Lists - and yes - that could cause and "infinite loop" - I'm looking to see if that can be detected as well as expanding those that can be.

Comment: @MajidAkbari - I was rather hoping to avoid Cursors for performance reasons - The table could contain several thousand lists, each with 1 to several hundred members as well as zero to many nested lists.

Comment: @Martyn Could you please add some sample table data to your post please? What I think would be helpful is what does a list which holds another list look like as a row and what does a list with an actual member and not a list look like?

Comment: @RyanWilson - Sample (obfuscated) data added to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
;WITH list_structure AS
(
    SELECT CAST(l1.listname AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS list_path,
    l1.listname,
    CAST(l1.membername AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS membername
    FROM lists l1
    WHERE l1.listname NOT IN (SELECT membername FROM lists)
UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(list_structure.list_path + '/' + l.listname AS NVARCHAR(255)), 
    l.listname,
    l.membername
    FROM lists l
    INNER JOIN list_structure
    ON l.listname = list_structure.membername
)

SELECT list_path + '/' + list_structure.membername FROM list_structure
WHERE list_structure.membername NOT IN (SELECT listname FROM lists)
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

To detect direct self-references:

```
select l1.listname, l1.membername from lists l1
where exists (select * from lists l2 where l1.membername = l2.listname)
```

If that works, then anything not returned by that query can be used to produce your 2nd result.